# is mechanize one of the most popular libraries for automating web site interactions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

is mechanize one of the most popular libraries for automating web site interactions in Ruby?

It's been a while since I've needed to automate a bit of web site interaction and just wanted to check there isn't now some more highly used/newer alternative...

Comment: Have you tried checking Ruby Toolbox?

Comment: yep - didn't seem to have a category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last I checked (about 3 months ago), `mechanize` was still the most popular library and was what I ended up using (though I did have a random HTTPS error that I never fixed on my development machine).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of popularity, nothing else even comes close. There are some other interesting projects but the only time I consider using something other than mechanize is when there's lots of javascript, and on those occasions it's watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worthwhile to note that Mechanize was originally written in Perl, and that there's both a Ruby and a Python implementation.

And yes, Ruby's flavor of Mechanize is the most active, and probably the most popular library for automating web site interactions.

Take a look at the stars or the code frequency for the different projects (according to GitHub as of Feb 2013):

[Ruby Mechanize (~1300 stars, lots of code committed in 2012)](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/graphs/code-frequency)

[Python Mechanize (~260 stars, not much code committed in 2012)](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/graphs/code-frequency)

[Perl Mechanize (~30 stars, some code committed in 2012)](https://github.com/libwww-perl/WWW-Mechanize/graphs/code-frequency)